# min, max threshold in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

@Hightcharts stock
How can i have two threshold's ? for min,max in this graph http://jsfiddle.net/CYJAk/16/

As an example in here there's only one threshold set
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.6/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/area/

or

instead of threshold option in highcharts, is there way i can show red spots/points when
they fall out of min:max range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to approach this problem is to add two plot lines on the chart indicating
the minimum and maximum values allowed.

Let's say you would like to apply this to the yAxis and set a minimum of 100 and a maximum of 500, you can like so:

```
var min = 100;
var max = 500;

yAxis: {

                min: min - 100,
                max: max + 100,
                plotLines: [{
                    id: 'limit-min',
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                    width: 2,
                    value: min,
                    zIndex: 0
                }, {
                    id: 'limit-max',
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                    width: 2,
                    value: max,
                    zIndex: 0
                }]
            }
```

The reason for adding and subtracting 100 to the max and min values is because we'd like the plot lines to be visible on the chart.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

why not render a second band behind (or over) this series which contains the normal range. Then you could see easily which points fall outside that range.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer, I created a quick code sample. I think if you have the red line for min, you can clear see which points are falling below your allowable minimum.

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>How to add min and max thresholds in Highcharts</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sales By Month',
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Metrics',
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Revenue'
                },
                plotLines: [{

                color: '#FF0000',
                dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                width: 2,
                value: 22,
                zIndex: 0,
                label : {
                    text : 'Goal'
                }
            }, {
                color: '#008000',
                dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                width: 2,
                value: 10,
                zIndex: 0,
                label : {
                    text : 'Loss'
                }
            }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': $'+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Revenue',
                data: [21000, 24000, 27500, 33000, 29000, 26000, 19000, 21000, 25000, 29000, 23000, 18000]
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Working demo on Edit Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iavinash/kyUaR/). It may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer, I created a quick code sample. I think if you have the red line for min, you can clear see which points are falling below your allowable minimum.

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>How to add min and max thresholds in Highcharts</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sales By Month',
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Metrics',
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Revenue'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    id: 'limit-min',
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                    width: 2,
                    value: 22000,
                    zIndex: 0,
                    label : {
                        text : 'Last Year\'s Minimum Revenue'
                    }
                }, {
                    id: 'limit-max',
                    color: '#008000',
                    dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                    width: 2,
                    value: 32000,
                    zIndex: 0,
                    label : {
                        text : 'Last Year\'s Maximum Revenue'
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': $'+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Revenue',
                data: [21000, 24000, 27500, 33000, 29000, 26000, 19000, 21000, 25000, 29000, 23000, 18000]
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Working demo [here](http://www.blueflame-software.com/blog/demo/how-to-add-min-and-max-thresholds-in-highcharts/).

Comment: You need to document your work here - link based answers are not usually acceptable.

Comment: Your link-only answers lead directly to your website.  This is not a valuable contribution to the community.